# Why is Alert working as a pause?

Tags: javascript

First of all, apologies if this question was answered before.

I'm writing a code in JS to read an Excel File, get the value of the first cell in the column, search for it (it's an ISBN code, which I'm searching with the Google Books API) and get other relevant info, made available through the search (like Title, Subtitle and Author), then proceed to the next line and repeat the process.

My problem is writing the new data back in the Excel File. The code is writing all info in the last used row in the file. While using window.alert to flag the code, I noticed that when the alert was in a for loop, right before the search was initiated, the new data was inserted just fine, but if I tried to use a pause (like a timer function or a while loop to consume time) it didn't help at all.

What I want to know is why that behavior might be happening and, if possible, of course, a possible solution for my problem, since having to use alert as a pause isn't exactly the most interesting solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's because that's just how `alert()` works. It completely freezes the execution of code in the page. (well, almost completely)

Comment: `alert()` blocks all further execution of javascript in the main foreground thread.  It and a couple other functions like `prompt()` are unique in that regard.  They are known as blocking functions in that no other javascript can run until they are done.  `setTimeout()` is not blocking.  Other javascript can run.  `setTimeout()` just schedules your javascript to run sometime in the future.  It does not block.  If you want better help, please post your code so we can help you structure it appropriately.

Comment: We really can't help you with seeing your code.

Comment: will do so tomorrow, since I don't have access to the code at home

Comment: @htcoelho we don't need your code, there's nothing wrong with what's happening. This is what's **supposed** to happen. If you need to continue execution, use a web worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When browsers show a native modal interaction widget, such as an alert, it transitions into a state that waits for the response. In this state, it is allowed to redraw the page and process certain low level events. Here's the code from Mozilla Firefox that `alert()` and `confirm()` use:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/prompts/src/nsPrompter.js#434

This `openRemotePrompt` function doesn't return until the user clicks "OK" on the alert. However browser behaves differently while the alert is open. A loop repeatedly calls `thread.processNextEvent` to do certain kinds of work until the dialog is closed. (It doesn't run the application's JavaScript code, since that's meant to be single-threaded.)

When you use a pure JavaScript busy wait, for example, by looping until a certain wall time, the browser doesn't take these measures to keep things moving. Most noticeably, the UI won't redraw while the JavaScript code is looping.

Comment: I'm marking this one as the answer, since it feels more complete to me. Anyway, I'd like to thank you all for explaining me what's happening. It really helped me understand and think of possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

Alert will always stop **all** execution of code, **except for web workers**. Therefore, If you need to continue execution, use a web worker. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) for reference (the note part covers this topic partially)

Comment: If its how alert works you better show some reference or make it a comment.

Comment: Which part of my comment is not polite? If it is not polite flag it so the moderators can judge! w3schools and almost every site is a better reference than you or me, we are not writing paper so even wikipedia could be a reference too! the point of reference here is to let OP learn something because your answer has no more value than a comment.

Comment: Which part be more specific, what did I said that offend you? Thanks god stackoverflow have many moderators so rise a flag for my comment.

Comment: I didnt even vote you down, I just leave a comment for you to make your answer better!

Comment: @AliAmiri I didn't mean you were **rude** but its more like you're demanding something I **owe** you

Comment: You don't owe Ali Amiri. It's just that Stack Overflow has rules about what should be an answer and what should be a comment.